# How do I use check_box in a table form so that I can access the table attributes in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actionview

I have a table inside of a form, with the following code:

```
<tbody>
        <% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>

            <td class="collapsing">
                <div class="ui fitted slider checkbox">
                <%= f.check_box appointment.id %><label></label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><%= appointment.name %></td>

        <% end %>
</tbody>
```

So a checkbox is generated, but if I'm selecting multiple checkboxes, I get

`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qCo02PG1F2wrSK4sxCQiQLzuhG4vZypgd9p5LzP9Sp7uZQFHs8tTTitLR++VXVK3f68P0qih+iQBlZt9anG01Q==", "cleaner"=>{"4"=>"1", "5"=>"0", "2"=>"0", "3"=>"0", "6"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Request", "cleaner_id"=>"1"}`

So to access the appointments, I would do `parameters["cleaner"]` and get `<ActionController::Parameters {"4"=>"1", "5"=>"1", "2"=>"0", "3"=>"0", "6"=>"0"} permitted: false>`

What I am looking to do is get an array instead of a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hash class provides a [`keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-keys) method, which will return the keys of a hash as an array.
So `parameters["cleaner"].keys` is what you are (probably) looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use some customization on the check boxes, something like:

```
<% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
  <td class="collapsing">
    <div class="ui fitted slider checkbox">
      <%= check_box_tag "cleaner[appointment_ids][]", appointment.id %><label></label>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td><%= appointment.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

That way you should have something like `params[cleaner][appointment_ids]` to get the selected appointments